# Конфликт скрола в RecyclerView с жестом Fling

Tags: android, recyclerview

Опишу то, что, как мне кажется, может иметь отношение к проблеме.
Имеется RecyclerView, заполненный объектами из CardView и TextView. В `onBindViewHolder()` адаптера вызывается метод изменения видимости TextView:

```
void setItemText(ViewHolder viewHolder, Item item) {
    super.setItemText(viewHolder, item);
    if (mModel.isShowcaseNamesShow()) { viewHolder.mName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
    else { viewHolder.mName.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
}
```

В Activity прописан GestureDetector для обработки жеста Fling, который меняет ширину layout'а с RecyclerView и состояние переменой `isShowcaseNamesShow`, а также вызывает `notifyDataSetChanged()` у адаптера для обновления содержимого.
Событие касания передается GestureDetector'у в методе `dispatchTouchEvent()` Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

В результате, если во время Fling'а задевается RecyclerView, то срабатывает его скрол, и предметы в нем подпрыгивают, зависают в неположенных местах и криво отображаются (см. скриншоты ниже):

[image] [image]

В этом, собственно, и проблема. Что происходит и как это исправить? Изначально использовал ListView вместо RecyclerView, таких выкрутасов не было.
Возможно стоит отметить, что использую стабильные id в адаптере (`setHasStableIds(true)`), переопределяя метод:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    int nameRes = mItems.get(position).getNameRes();
    if (nameRes != 0) return nameRes;
    else return mItems.get(position).getName().hashCode();
}
```

Пытался решить вопрос следующим образом - не передавать событие касания дальше, если срабатывает Fling:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) return true;
    else return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Конфликт решается, но это мне не подходит, так как приводит к другим проблемам из-за потери событий касания (например, молчит `onTouchListener` предметов другого RecyclerView при детектировании Fling'а)

P.S. Впервые задаю вопрос по программированию, так что прошу прощения за большой объем и воду, не знал как сократить). И да, начал изучать Android недавно, мое первое приложение, если я что-то неправильно делаю или думаю, хотелось бы услышать советы и объективную критику.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так: вместо перехвата события касания в `dispatchTouchEvent` у `Activity` прицепил слушатель `OnItemTouchListener` к `RecyclerView` непосредственно:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new ItemTouchListener());
```

Код слушателя:

```
class ItemTouchListener extends RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Событие касания сначала приходит в `onInterceptTouchEvent` и перехватывается при совершении жеста Fling, в противном случае идет дальше для обработки скрола в RecyclerView системой.